# Avoiding type name conflicts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces

I am writing a static library in Swift that will be reused in multiple projects. The problem is class and struct names I am using are common and can easily conflict with other libraries/frameworks. I don't see any obvious way to create my own namespace in Swift. What's the best way to avoid name collision between classes in multiple libraries/frameworks?

Comment: There isn't really anything else you can do other than "give different names"... That said, name collisions aren't that bad, because you can prefix the module name to resolve them, like `Foundation.Timer` vs `YourModule.Timer`.

Comment: The traditional approach in iOS has been to use a two letter prefix e.g. `UITextFiled` `CBPeripheral`

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess you meant to say the Objective-C approach :) In Swift, you can use the module name to resolve name conflicts, which wasn't possible in Obj-C. Hence the reason prefixing all types came to life in Obj-C.

Answer (score 9):

You don't to have to avoid. Just use the name you like. Then when you want to access to your class/struct/protocol..., just use your module name as a namespace.

Example:

```
import MyModule

let a: MyModule.Result // the Result type defined inside the `MyModule`
let b: Result // Swift's Result type
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, if there is a conflict, you can always fully qualify the symbol name with the module name (See Cong's answer.)

Apple's suggested way to handle this in the days of Objective-C was to use your intials or your company's initials as a prefix for your symbol names. I'm not a big fan of that since it creates ugly names that obscure the underlying meaning.

Using an abbreviated version of the module name/framework name is a little better, and what Apple tends to do, e.g. UIKit views are `UIView`s, and AFNetworking's connection object might be an `AFNConnection`.

Others are arguing strongly in the comments that this is no longer needed and no longer recommended. (Like I said, I've never liked it anyway.)

Comment: _"Apple's suggested way to handle this is to use your intials or your company's initials as a prefix for your symbol names."_ Could you please back that up with a reference? AFAIK that's the Obj-C way of doing things, Apple proposes no such thing in Swift.

Comment: I don't remember where I saw this, and it may well hark back to the days of Objective-C. However, I submit as evidence Apple's frameworks, which consistently follow this pattern. UIKit, Core Location, Core Image. Core ML,

Comment: That isn't really evidence though - considering all are written in Objective-C, not Swift. If you check the newer Apple frameworks, like Combine or SwiftUI, which are purely Swift, none of the types have prefixes.

Comment: The prefixed names were a crutch for C and ObjC's lack of namespaces, and doesn't apply to Swift code. All "top level" symbols in Swift are implicitly name-spaced by their defining module. Even the standard library, which is name-spaced with `Swift.`, which can be useful e.g. for calling the global `max` function from an extension on array (where `max` refers to `Array.max(by:)`) by using `Swift.max(a, b)`.